# How do I change the order of columns in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the union of following query,

```
Select 'C' as c 
Union
Select 'p' as p
union
Select 'BA' as 'BA'
```

but the columns are coming like in BA, C, P but I want to change the order i.e. C, P, BA

I tried order by C by applying the Select over this but not working.

Comment: You mean order of _rows_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need another column to sort by. In your data, the value `'BA'` has a lower value than `'C'`, which has a lower value than `'p'` (strings are sorted in  the collations alphabetical order, left to right). As result `ORDER BY c` would mean that `'BA'` is first, and `'p'` is last.

Personally, for what you have I would use `VALUES` as well, rather than 3 `UNION ALL` queries:

```
SELECT V.c
FROM (VALUES(1,'C'),
            (2,'p'),
            (3,'BA'))V(I,c)
ORDER BY V.I;
```

*To expand on my comment about collations, some collations sort characters as `'ABCD...YZabcd...yz'` while others `'AaBbCcDd...YyZz'` This means that for some, a value like `'Zebra'` would be before `'aardvark'` in some collations, and in others after. I **assume** here you aren't using a collation that orders all upper case letters first, which are less commonly used.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select 'C' as c 
Union All
Select 'p' as p
union All
Select 'BA' as 'BA'
```

Result:

```
C
p
BA
```